# Resuming an uncoverged ergm run with ergm package in R

Tags: r, statnet

I am using the `ergm` package in `R` to explore exponential random graph models for network data. Here's the network:

```
gn
 Network attributes:
  vertices = 678 
  directed = TRUE 
  hyper = FALSE 
  loops = FALSE 
  multiple = FALSE 
  bipartite = FALSE 
  total edges= 1663 
    missing edges= 0 
    non-missing edges= 1663 

 Vertex attribute names: 
    indegree membership num_tweets vertex.names 

 Edge attribute names not shown
```

After fitting simpler models, one with a term for `edges` and `mutual` and one with `edges`, `mutual`, and `nodefactor("membership", base = 4)` (where `membership` is a factor with four levels), I fit a model with `nodematch("membership", diff = T)` added, as follows:

```
model1 <- ergm(gn ~ edges + 
                    mutual + 
                    nodefactor("membership", base = 4) +
                    nodematch("membership", diff = T)
                    )
```

While the previous models converged, this model led to this message:

```
MCMLE estimation did not converge after 20 iterations. The estimated coefficients may not be accurate. Estimation may be resumed by passing the coefficients as initial values; see 'init' under ?control.ergm for details.
```

As instructed, I took a look at `?control.ergm`: `Passing control.ergm(init=coef(prev.fit)) can be used to “resume” an uncoverged ergm run, but see enformulate.curved.`

OK, this sounds good, I searched for how `control.ergm` is used, and found an example from [this page](http://statnet.csde.washington.edu/workshops/SUNBELT/EUSN/ergm/ergm_tutorial.html), and I tested that this worked by passing `control = control.ergm(MCMLE.maxit = 50)` as an argument, which increased the `number of times the parameters for the MCMC should be updated by maximizing the MCMC likelihood` from 20 to 50. I then did the following:

```
model1a <- ergm(gn ~ edges + 
                    mutual + 
                    nodefactor("membership", base = 4) +
                    nodematch("membership", diff = T),
                    control = control.ergm(init=coef(prev.fit))
                    )
```

But, this message is returned: `Error in coef(prev.fit) : object 'prev.fit' not found`.

I also tried to pass the model object (i.e., `model1a`) instead of `prev.fit`, but that led to this not-too-productive error:

```
Error in if (drop) { : argument is not interpretable as logical
In addition: Warning message:
In if (drop) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

So, how can I "resume" an unconverged model by passing `control.ergm(init = coef(prev.fit))` - or via a different approach?

Comment: You are right--you need to pass an ergm object (or vector of coefficients) to the `init` argument--the `prev.fit` term is a placeholder for that (poorly presented in documentation). I cannot reproduce your error. Check to see if you are passing an ergm object (`class(model1)`) or try assigning the coefficients to a vector (`coefs <- coef(model1)`) and pass that to the `init` argument. Also--there are other (better) ways to get convergence using burn-in, thinning, and sample size.

Comment: Thanks, `class(model3)` returns `[1] "ergm"`, but assigning the coefficients to a vector and then passing that to `init` worked! I'd like to check out those other ways (burn-in, thinning, & sample size). if you could point me in the right direction (even more than you already have, thanks again), I would be appreciative

Comment: Default values for thinning interval and sample size are 1024 and for burn-in is 16384. I like to set my burn-in at 100000 and other values at 10000, so `control=control.ergm(MCMC.burnin=100000, MCMC.samplesize=10000, MCMC.interval=10000`. This does dramatically increase computational time, so start small and work your way up. That said, a poorly specified model will have convergence problems as well. For example, if the reciprocity isn't that high, asymmetric may be a better term.